# Azure DevOps searches for nuget package in the wrong source

Tags: c#, azure-devops, nuget, nuget-config

I have a .NET solution which needs packages from 3 sources:

- Nuget.org
- My own organization
- Another feed

I have a **nuget.config** file with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="MyOrga" value="..." />
    <add key="TheOtherFeed" value="..." />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

I have, in my projects, a reference to the package `MyPackage` which is in `MyOrga`, and to the package `MyOtherPackage`, which is in `TheOtherFeed`.

In my Azure DevOps pipeline, during the **Nuget Restore** task, it successfully finds the nuget.config and finds the 3 feeds.
However, I get this error, which makes my task fail:

```
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1301: Failed to retrieve information about 'MyPackage' from remote source '<TheOtherFeed>/MyPackage/index.json'.
```

So it's basically only trying to get the package from the wrong feed, even though it found all 3 feeds (including the correct one). What did I do wrong?

Comment: Hi, can you confirm if you have the NuGetAuthenticate@1 task before the nuget restore task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that error if your feed is not authenticated.
Try adding a NuGetAuthenticate:

`- task: NuGetAuthenticate@1`

before you restore.